# How do i edit the "Account" button in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am running the latest Magento ( 1.9 ) with the Default theme and right now, in the top right region of the header i see the Account and CART buttons.

What i want to do is edit the Account button into something else however I spent the last 2 hours trying to find the place where I can edit it.

Can you please guide me in the right direction ?

Comment: Are you just trying to change the wording to something else?

Comment: Hello, yes, i am just trying to change the wording into something else...

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate to your theme's app layout directory, for example;

root/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout

The top links are declared as a position in the template in the xml and can be added to by the different extensions.  The account link is defined in customer.xml.  If you search that file for "top.links" you will find it;

```
<!-- Mage_Customer -->
<reference name="top.links">
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
</reference>
```

After you modify this, you will need to flush your cache for the changes to take effect.

Best
Tom